# Question de grammaire, pronom « y »

Tags: grammaire, expressions

Qu'elle est la formule optimale, dire :

> L'organisation des tables d'une base de données a pour but de s'assurer que leurs dépendances y soient correctement appliquées.

ou bien :

> L'organisation des tables d'une base de données a pour but de s'assurer que leurs dépendances soient correctement appliquées.

Comment: Il faudrait fournir plus de contexte et expliquer pourquoi tu hésites.

Comment: moi je veux connaitre plus de detaile sur l'utilisation de la preposition "y" alors j'ai mis une phrase, genre est ce que c'est judicieux de l'utiliser dans les redactions scientifiques ou c juste pour le langage; si vous voyez ce que je veux dire et merci d'avance

Comment: Le problème est que tu n'as pas mis une phrase mais un morceau de phrase. La présence du pronom *y* n'est pas lié au niveau de langue, ou à une différence entre le parlé et l'écrit.

Comment: l'organisation des tables d'une base de donnees a pour but de s'assurer que leurs dépendances y soient correctement appliquées.

Comment: voila la phrase je pensai que sa n'aurai pas d'importance desolé

Answer (score 1):

En ajoutant "**y**", vous précisez le lieu où doivent s'appliquer les dépendances : "y" tenant lieu de complément d'objet indirect signifiant "**à *cela***", ***cela*** étant le sujet de la proposition précédente, c'est à dire la "Base de données".

En enlevant le "y", vous affirmez que le processus a pour but que les dépendances soient correctement appliquées, mais sans préciser dans quel environnement est considérée cette application des dépendances.

Ainsi, si l'environnement désigné est la base de données elle-même, il est donc
préférable de conserver "y", qui suffit à préciser ce fait. Il semble que ce soit le cas, puisque les "dépendances" sont bien une problématique de la base de données elle-même, n'est-ce pas?

Comment: Merci beaucoup maintenant j'y vois claire grâce à vous.

Answer (score 0):

La forme avec *y* et la forme sans sont toutes deux grammaticales.

Si l'expression attendue est *appliquer des dépendances à une base de donnée*, j'écrirais cette phrase comme ceci :

> Le processus d'organisation des tables d'une base de données a pour but de s'assurer que leurs dépendances y sont correctement appliquées.

Si ce qui est attendu est *appliquer les dépendances* sans plus de précision :

> Le processus d'organisation des tables d'une base de données a pour but de s'assurer que leurs dépendances sont correctement appliquées.